# What is wrong with this My-SQL statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, exists

Here's the statement:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Players WHERE ID = 'Something') BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Players(ID, Msg) VALUES ('Something', 'Custom MSG')
END
```

Error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near `IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Players WHERE ID = 'Something') BEGIN` at line 1.

Expected results: I want to make a row/column(Not 100% sure.) that has the ID of the player, and a template message.

Edit: What would be the best way to do this and why?

Comment: I'm not sure that there's anything *right* with it :-(

Comment: it looks like you're trying to use TSQL syntax in MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use the `IF` statement outside of a procedure or routine in MySQL. Use the `INSERT IGNORE` or the `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statements instead.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO Player (ID, Msg)
VALUES 
  ('Something', 'Custom MSG');
```

OR

```
INSERT INTO Player (ID, Msg)
VALUES 
  ('Something', 'Custom MSG')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  Msg = Msg; --  or Msg = VALUES(Msg) to update to the new value.
```

There should be a `PRIMARY KEY` or a `UNIQUE KEY` defined on the `ID` column to work.

Check it with this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e738f)

Comment: 2nd one is most suitable to user as first one will replace other values based on id....

Comment: @ZafarMalik: Agreed. Changed the order of the suggested solutions.

Comment: What would be best to use IGNORE or DUPLICATE and what is the difference between the two?

Comment: If you want to update the record even if it is exist, use DUPLICATE (see the comment after the last line). If you want to ignore the insert when the record exist and you don't want to touch the existing record, use IGNORE

Comment: The thing is I only need one ID for each player, I don't want to create more then one ID for each player.

Comment: The thing you are talking about is called  `UNIQUE KEY constraint` or you in your case, it could be the `PRIMARY KEY`, but this is another question.

Comment: @JosephFoote: It is clear that you want to keep single record in your table...but if you want to keep existing record without change then use ignore...but if you want to keep latest entry then use duplicate....

Answer (score 0):

A much better approach to that would be to simply use the `REPLACE INTO` syntax of MySQL. Just make sure your ID field is primary key and write your query as:

```
REPLACE INTO Players(ID, Msg) VALUES ('Something', 'Custom MSG');
```

This will INSERT if no row is found, and UPDATE if it finds a previously existing row, based on primary key. [Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) you can find relevant documentation.

Comment: REPLACE INTO is not an UPDATE when the row is found, but a DELETE and and INSERT combined. Keep this in mind. In this case the result is similar, but with AI columns the result will be different. Use this statement carefully. Also, the REPLACE can fail or delete records from another table, when it is executed on a primary key which has referencing foreign keys!

Answer (score -3):

You need to use it inside a procedure and it ends with END IF;

```
Create procedure proc_name
as
Begin
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Players WHERE ID = 'Something') BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Players(ID, Msg) VALUES ('Something', 'Custom MSG');
END IF;
end;
```

Comment: This is a solution to a problem that doesn't exist.